# Sum rule for integration

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

By performing integration in mathematica it seems that,
\begin{equation}\int_{-2}^{1}dx\int_{0}^{3}dy\,\frac{x}{x-y}\log\left(x^{2}-y^{2}\right)-\int_{-2}^{1}dx\int_{0}^{3}dy\,\frac{y}{x-y}\log\left(x^{2}-y^{2}\right)\\\neq\int_{-2}^{1}dx\int_{0}^{3}dy\,\log\left(x^{2}-y^{2}\right)\end{equation}.

How this could be true?! if we just add the integrands they seems to lead to a vanishing results.

[image]

Comment: At several points in your domain, you're trying to take the log of zero or a negative number.  When you juggle infinities like that, you get silly results.

Comment: There is nothing silly here.. do you think that the condition for adding integrands apply?

Comment: Not when the integrals don't converge.  What's $\infty - \infty$?

Comment: All the integrals which are involved coverges, even separately.

Comment: Your region of integration is the rectangle $[-2,1]$ x $ [0.3].$  If you plot that and draw the lines $y=x$ and $y=-x$, those lines cut two triangles off your region.  Your functions are not even defined in those triangles.  How can you think the integrals converge?

Comment: I added the output from mathematica. As it turns out - it can give a definite value for each of these integrals. For this calculation we can assume that I work on the complex plane and negative logs are allowed.

Comment: Then $x$ and $y$ are complex variables...?   That's odd.  And which branch of log are you using?  And you're still dividing by zero at infinitely many points.

Comment: No, $x$ and $y$ are dummy real variables. The branch is assumed arbitrary. The singularities that you pointed, when $x=y$ are removable.

Comment: Then you're not working in the complex plane.  I don't believe the singularities are removable.

Comment: I do, there is an additional complex part which I dropped for simplification. You're right, these are not removable singularities, but probably due to some symmetry they cancel. As you see in the attached image, as a matter of fact, this integral has a value.

Comment: Just to be more clear, in the actual problem the denominator is $\frac{1}{x-y-i\epsilon}$ and similar thing is included in the $log$.

Comment: If what you say is true, then the answer to your original question is "you jumped a branch cut."

Comment: This sounds exactly like what is happening. Thanks Goddard! Mathematically speaking, we learn from this example that the condition to add two integrands together is *absolute* convergence (and not just convergence), right?

Answer (score 2):

The functions involved contain many discontinuities, so the integrals are all *improper* integrals. As such, even assigning a meaningful value to each is not guaranteed - and in this case, operating over the real numbers we have no such values. If that happens, then we cannot safely sum the integrals together because we are working with undefined values.

For example, looking at the right-hand side, $\log(x^2 - y^2)$ is not defined when $|y| > |x|$, which represents more than half of the region of integration.